# Android: text in TextView is not trimmed

Tags: android

I am setting the text of a `TextView` several times like this:

```
activity?.runOnUiThread {
    textViewState.text = status
}
```

The text is usually aligned at the center of the view:

```xml
android:textAlignment="center"
```

So far nothing special, but sometimes when the `status` gets shorter, like from `"finished"` to `"idle"`, the text in the view is aligned to the left.
This seems to be caused by that the text of the `TextView` (a `CharSequence`) is not

```
['i', 'd', 'l', 'e']
```

(as it should be) but

```
['i', 'd', 'l', 'e', '', '', '', '']
```

So the buffer seems to be too large and the `TextView` displays a whitespaced string.

Is there any way to tell the `TextView` to reset the buffer? Or another way to fix this problem?

Comment: Width `wrap_content` and text alignment center both how ? View will take width only the size equal to content .

Comment: @ADM It should, yes. But even if it is set to `match_parent`, the problem remains. Removed it from question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that seems to work:

```
val statusArray = status?.toCharArray() ?: CharArray(0)

activity?.runOnUiThread {
    textViewState.setText(statusArray, 0, status?.length ?: 0)
}
```

This passes the length of the `status` explicitly and seems to bypass some internal performance optimization.